# how to keep same url structure for our new magento website

Tags: magento2

how do we keep same URL structure for my new Magento 2 website ex if we have this URL https://www.papilior.com/jewellery/earring/diamond-earrings in our existing site.how do we keep same in a new store.

Comment: I would like to suggest to ask the question at [Magento Stack Exchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/)